# Refrigerate Cod After Cooking

Tags: food-safety, fish, refrigerator, reheating, cod

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Resources for reheatable meals, specifically fish?](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/8823/resources-for-reheatable-meals-specifically-fish)
>   [How long can I store a food in the pantry, refrigerator, or freezer?](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/21068/how-long-can-i-store-a-food-in-the-pantry-refrigerator-or-freezer)

Is it okay to refrigerate Cod (and other kinds of fish) once cooked and eat the next day?

If so, can you reheat it before eating?

Comment: I disagree it is a duplicate. I'm interested in refridgeration of fish after being cooked and its shelf life, also whether it is safe to reheat. The duplicate question makes no mention of how to store once cooked and the length of time it can be stored in that way. It instead looks at what recipies reheat in the microwave well, which i'm not intrested in.

Comment: Isn't it clear that it's safe to reheat from that question, and that it must last at least a day in the fridge? (And what cooked foods *aren't* safe to reheat but can be eaten cold?)

Comment: Can I make the suggestion you alter the second question, so it comes up when you search for terms like fish refrigerate etc... If I could have found the question by search I wouldn't have had to ask. Cheers for the down votes though.

Comment: Chris, we can't directly control search results. I can see if there's anything obvious keeping it from ranking, but stackexchange search isn't amazing. This is why we have the duplicate mechanism - to point people to what they didn't or couldn't find by searching.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's fine to refrigerate cooked fish. Many types of fish are excellent (better, even) served cold -- shrimp and salmon are good examples. If you can eat it cold, it's hard to see how reheating would pose any additional risk.

There are some other considerations, though. It's easy to overcook fish, which leaves it dry and less than tender, and that goes double if you're reheating. Use low heat (or low power in a microwave) and be careful not to cook too long. Some sauce will help keep the fish reheat, but avoid storing the fish in a strongly acidic sauce (like lemon juice) as acid will change the fish over time even in the fridge. And avoid reheating fishy things in the microwave at work if you value your relationship with your coworkers -- the smell often lingers.

Comment: Shrimp is fish? Lol

Comment: @Jay Zoologically speaking, no. Gastronomically speaking, close enough.

Comment: Great points. I usually add a bit of water to keep the moisture in, personally. I also wrap fish up in tinfoil in a pouch with a bit of water, olive oil, and more spices if it needs it. Heating it up like this keeps the moisture in. If you take the fish out for a little while before heating it up, you can also avoid having to heat it up for too long and losing moisture or overcooking it (since room temperature to heated is a shorter temperature change than refrigerated to heated). You can heat it up like this in either the oven or the toaster oven. Just put a tray underneath in case it drips.